# How to check is login free java?

Tags: java

I have method like this. Why when I set the login that is not in the database always gets true ?

```
public boolean isLoginFree(String login) {

        String loginfree = null;

        try {
            PreparedStatement pst = null;
            pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT login from User where login = ?");
            pst.setString(1, login);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                logintemp = rs.getString("login");

                if ((logintemp.equals(login) == true)) {
                    return false;                           //login free
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        return true;            //login busy

    }
```

Comment: Run your code with a debugger and find out.

Comment: logic flaw (what id you don't get any row returned, you need to return false) and there might be an Exception as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to see if the `login` value is already stored in the database. An easier way:

```
public boolean isLoginFree(String login) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select login " + 
                                                 "from User " + 
                                                 "where login=?");
    pst.setString(1, login);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    return !rs.first();
}
```

This will return `false` if there's (at least) a row in the resultset (i.e. the login is already stored in the table), and `true` otherwise.

If you want to do it using "the long way":

```
public boolean isLoginFree(String login) {
    boolean ans = false;
    try(PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select login " +
                                                     "from User " +
                                                     "where login = ?")) {
        pst.setString(1, login);
        try(ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {
            ans = !rs.first();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            // Handle the exeption for the result set
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        // Handle the exeption for the prepared statement
    }
    return ans;
}
```

In both cases, the function should return `true` if there are no rows in the result set (that's the reason for the `!`: if the value is already there, then it's not free, so the result should be false... at least that's the way I see it).

Comment: I write result like that System.out.println(db.isLoginFree("logass"));

Comment: Look:  String login1 = "ccc";
        String login2 = "logP"; <----- in database               true
true

Comment: Use a mysql client (the CLI, Workbench, MyAdmin, etcetera) and see what happens when you run your query. If the `login` value is already there, then my function(s) should return `false` (check the edit)

Answer (score 1):

If you get an exception from that method, or you don't return from your `while` loop, you'll always execute the `return true` line at the bottom of your method.

It'd be more straightforward to only have one point of exit.  Set a boolean variable in your method and only set it when something positive happens in your loop.  This means introducing a `break` into the loop.

Here's a sample.

```
public boolean isLoginFree(String login) {
    boolean result = false;
    String loginfree = null;

    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT login from User where login = ?");
        pst.setString(1, login);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            logintemp = rs.getString("login");

            if ((logintemp.equals(login)) {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    return result;

}
```

EDIT:  If you want  a query to check if the value exists in the database, then you really want a `NOT EXISTS` query.

```
SELECT 1 from User WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * from User WHERE login = ?);
```

You could then use the result of `getBoolean(0)` instead.

Here's what that would look like:

```
public boolean isLoginFree(String login) {
    boolean result = true;

    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT 1 from User WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * from User WHERE login = ?)");
        pst.setString(1, login);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            if (rs.getBoolean(0)) {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    return result;

}
```

Comment: So that means that `logintemp` is equivalent to the string in your `login` column in your database.  Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I write result like that System.out.println(db.isLoginFree("logass"));

Comment: I just realized your query is circular.  You're getting back the same column that you're querying for.  You probably want to query for a boolean instead.

Comment: look on Barranka. I want to see if the lofin value is already stored in database

Comment: Right, I've made an adjustment to my answer.  Always, *always* ask the database for *exactly* what you want.